# how to redirect old tab after I submit to a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

I´m submitting a form in a new tab with:

```
<form action="xxx.php" target="_blank" method="post">
```

But the old tab stays in the form and I´d like to send it to another page after submit.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use header('Location: url.php');

Comment: This another post with the solution, check: [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773622/close-window-aft‌​er-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773622/close-window-aft‌​er-redirect)

Comment: Is not what I need. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Two Options :

1) Just remove the `target="_blank"` and redirect the form in the same page.

2) Use Jquery to perform a function after form is submitted :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) { 
    // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the form to open in another page with POST. Because is going to open a PDF file. but I´d like the previous tab to go to another page as well

Comment: I mean, I need it to open to different pages, one of them in a new tab

Comment: Then you can use in your form onsubmit="myFunction()" and in myFunction redirect the page.

Comment: But it will ignore all POST variables needed for the php file

Answer (score 0):

Made it!..

through GET

```
function load(){
                <?php
                        $url = "XXX.php?VAR=".$Z;
                        echo "window.open('$url');".PHP_EOL;
                        echo "window.location.href = 'YYY.php';";
                ?>
            }
```

Comment: Great ! if my comment helped you, please upvote it :)